# Allow users inserting with images along the text. How to implement and security-related issues

Tags: html, fckeditor

We have a website that we want to allow users insert images in all inserted text.

We where thinking to use fckeditor native functionalities to implement this.

Do you recommend? What kind of security related concerns do we have to do?

I notice that stack overflow use image servers to display images. Do you think is because security or is because disk size?

Thanks all of you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The security won't rely on FCKeditor. The security will rely on the server-side application.

Regarding the image server, it is usually used to optimize image distribution through caching and regional/continental servers (the goal is to reduce the round trip between the client and the server).